# Estimating white noise distribution for a AR(1) process in R

Tags: r, arima, autoregressive, prediction-interval

I have a time serie and I want to compile some scenarios following a AR(1) process.

I have used the package `forecast` from R to compute the coefficient with :

```
fit <- arima(data,order=c(1,0,0))
summary(fit)
Call:
arima(x = holdout, order = c(1, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept
      0.9710   117.5844
s.e.  0.0116    10.5430

sigma^2 estimated as 40.11:  log likelihood = -1186.53,  aic = 2379.06

Training set error measures:
                  ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE      ACF1
Training set -0.03900117 6.333147 4.324442 -0.293829 3.441437 0.9991266 0.2623189
```

Since a AR(1) process look like this :
$$x_t - \mu =\phi (x_{t-1}-\mu)+\varepsilon _t
$$
with $\varepsilon_t \sim {\mathcal {N}}(0 ,\sigma ^{2})$ (white noise).

my AR(1) model is :
$$ 
x_t - 117.5844 =0.9710 (x_{t-1}-117.5844)+\varepsilon _t 
$$

But I can't find how to estimate $\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}$.
If I use $\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}=0$, I have the same value as in R with `forecast(fit)` (the mean of my prediction).

How can I estimate $\varepsilon_t$, so that my scenarios fill fit in the intervals prediction from `forecast(fit)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with my simulations, so I thought that `sigma^2 estimated as 40.11` wasn't what I was looking for.
Well, it was ...